# Render structural markup and hide comments in org-present-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I'm giving a presentation with `org-present-mode`. I'd like to be able to center text and format quotations nicely, as described in the [structural markup](http://orgmode.org/manual/Paragraphs.html#Paragraphs) section of the org-mode docs. I'd also like to be able to make notes to myself in comments that won't display when I give the presentation.

Can I get `org-present-mode` to do this? I need to be able to execute elisp and open up new buffers within the presentation so exporting to HTML/PDF and viewing it externally isn't an option. If I could export it to a scratch buffer that's still in normal `org-mode` but with the formatting applied, that would work, but it's not clear to me how to do that.